# How to detect when the user sends HTML code to the server so I may display an error message in ASP.NET MVC 4

Tags: asp.net-mvc

Is there a way to detect when the user puts HTML code in a controller action parameter so that I may display an appropriate error message in ASP.NET MVC 4? By default, no properties and method parameters accept HTML.

I'd also like to enforce this validation on the client side.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
public class MyViewModel
{
    [AllowHtml]
    [RegularExpression(@"^((?!<\w+>).)*$", ErrorMessage = "Please do not use HTML tags")]
    public string SomeValue { get; set; }
}
```